# Parse Connection String into Struct in golang

Tags: parsing, go, connection-string

I'm new at golang and I need to parse a connection string into a struct to get specific elements of that. Example:

I have this:

```
"Data Source=mysqlserver.local,37001;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=usertest;Asynchronous Processing=True"
```

And I need to put that data on a struct that looks more or less like...

```
type ConnectionString struct {
    DataSource             string
    InitialCatalog         string
    UserID                 string
    AsynchronousProcessing string
}
```

I need to do something like the class `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` on .NET does.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did the following to solve my problem (I know its not perfect, but fits my needs very well)

```
func ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionstring string) ConnectionString {

    splittedcs := strings.Split(connectionstring, ";")

    csstruct := ConnectionString{}

    for i := 0; i < len(splittedcs); i++ {

        actualitem := splittedcs[i]
        splitteditem := strings.Split(actualitem, "=")

        fieldname := strings.ToUpper(strings.Replace(splitteditem[0], " ", "", -1))
        value := splitteditem[1]

        if fieldname == "DATASOURCE" || fieldname == "SERVER" {
            splittedport := strings.Split(value, ",")

            val := reflect.ValueOf(&csstruct)
            (val.Elem()).FieldByName(fieldname).SetString(splittedport[0])

            if len(splittedport) > 1 {
                (val.Elem()).FieldByName("PORT").SetString(splittedport[1])
            }

        } else {

            val := reflect.ValueOf(&csstruct)
            (val.Elem()).FieldByName(fieldname).SetString(value)
        }

        if csstruct.DATASOURCE != "" {
            csstruct.HOST = csstruct.DATASOURCE
        }

        if csstruct.SERVER != "" {
            csstruct.HOST = csstruct.SERVER
        }
    }

    return csstruct, nil
}

type ConnectionString struct {
    HOST                   string `json:"Host,omitempty"`
    DATASOURCE             string `json:"DataSource,omitempty"`
    SERVER                 string `json:"Server,omitempty"`
    INITIALCATALOG         string `json:"InitialCatalog,omitempty"`
    USERID                 string `json:"UserID,omitempty"`
    ASYNCHRONOUSPROCESSING string `json:"AsynchronousProcessing,omitempty"`
    PASSWORD               string `json:"Password,omitempty"`
    DATABASE               string `json:"Database,omitempty"`
    PORT                   string `json:"Port,omitempty"`
}
```